# WACK test fails for Metro Javascript app

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

The app works fine. But when I run the WACK tool, it fails and give the following error.

> FAILED Bytecode generation
>       Error Found: The bytecode generation test detected the following errors:
>           This package was deployed for development or authoring mode. Uninstall the package and re-install it normally.

Now I don't know how many times I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app in Release mode with any changes I thought might work. But no use.

So I created a package anyway. After creating the package, the packaging tool gave me a chance to run the app certificate. When I run it, I get the error below.

[image: Error screenshot]

I need to resolve both before I can move forward. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

From the [forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/45cf901e-c522-4484-94db-4d701a7d5dd2):

You might be running the Cert Kit against a version of the app that was deployed when you run the app directly from Visual Studio (ie: "deployed for development or authoring mode").

1) Uninstall the application from your local machine

2) Make sure you have the configuration dropdown in Visual Studio set to Release

3) Create the deployment package through the 'Store" menu.  Right click on the project, then Store -> Create App Package.

4) Follow the steps through the wizard.  When you reach the end, it will ask you if you want to run the Windows App Cert Kit.

Answer (score 1):

I have had someone that has seen that error.  In that case, it meant WACK had found a .html, .js, or .css file (or more than one) that was not saved as "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001". To save this way, open the file in Visual Studio, do File Save As, select "Save with Encoding..." (drop down from the Save button), and select the proper encoding.  You may need to check every file to ensure they are encoded properly.

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured out the deal with app certification tool. Ran it again today and I got a specific message this time... it said

> Application Error: Application Suspend was not detected for
>   application App. This could be because your application failed to
>   suspend correctly. Please consider re-running the test avoid
>   interacting with the application while tests are running.

Well, I had not implemented 'suspend' logic. I've got it in there now and it passes. Not sure what caused it to show the specific error message but I got a windows update this morning.

The WACK still remains an issue. Will update if I find out more.